How to connect to admin-ui panel using socket.io? Invalid namespace
My code is a simple example from any tutorial:
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const { instrument } = require('@socket.io/admin-ui');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://admin.socket.io"], 
  },
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello');
});

// Integrate Admin UI
instrument(io, {
  auth: false, 
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');

  socket.on('hello', (data) => {
    console.log('Received message from client:', data);
    socket.emit('hello-back', 'Hello from the server!');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3001');
});

But I'm getting error while connecting: Invalid namespace:

I tried different combinations of path and namespaces also tried to create namespace for admin - const adminNamespace = io.of('/admin').
but nothing helped. Where might be the problem?

The problem was related with extra slash in url http://localhost:3001/ - at end of link one excess "/".

This answer was posted as an edit to the question solved - how to connect to admin-ui panel using socket.io? Invalid namespace by the OP user377055 under CC BY-SA 4.0.

Thanks for posting this answer. I had marked this Q as needing a rollback and answer. Quick tip: I generally post "answers from the OP" as Community Wiki, but it is not a hard community requirement, as far as I know.
